# How to set the in line citation style globally in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using `biblatex` and `biber` to generate my bibliography and I would like to be able to control the style of a "normal" citation in the text globally in the preamble. At the moment I use `\supercite{}` every time to cite something. Ideally I would do something like use the `\cite{}` macro throughout my document and choose the style of citation either in the preamble or with a macro at the beginning of a chapter.

Is this possible?

I'm also using `biblatex-chem` if that influences anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `\autocite` command (instead of `\cite`), the various chem styles will take care of this for you: as far as I can see (IANAC), two of them use plain superscript by default, one uses superscript in brackets, and one uses italic numbers in parentheses. You can set your own `\autocite` using the autocite option: see page 52 of the Biblatex documentation for the details.

I have seen people who don't like typing the extra letters in `\autocite` using `\let\cite\autocite`. I'm never sure if that's a good idea (what if you want to "recover" `\cite` at some point) ... But I suppose if you are *careful* it should be OK. Safer, perhaps, if the length of the command is your concern, to define a short alternative of your own.

Comment: I thought adjusting the `\cite{}` was a bit dodgy and would probably cause me problems later. Thanks :)